# Overriding methods with generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-erasure

I introduced an abstract actor class which the abstract animal class is a subclass of. The problem I am facing now is that the act method in Rabbit class, (which a sub class of animal) does not work.

I get the following error

"Rabbit is not abstract and does not override abstract method `act(java.util.List<Actor>)` in Animal"

I thought that the act method in rabbit in fox would override the act method in Animal and Actor. How do I get around this problem?

Below is the abstract method in the Actor Class

```
abstract public void act(List<Actor>newActors);
```

This method is then overridden in the Animal class with the below code

```
abstract public void act(List<Actor> newAnimals);
```

This method is then overridden in the rabbit and fox classes with the below, which is where the error arises.

```
  public void act(List<Animal> newRabbits)
    {
        incrementAge();
        if(isAlive()) {
            giveBirth(newRabbits);            
            // Try to move into a free location.
            Location newLocation = getField().freeAdjacentLocation(getLocation());
            if(newLocation != null) {
                setLocation(newLocation);
            }
            else {
                // Overcrowding.
                setDead();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the method signature. A method is overriden when the signature equals the signature of the method it wants to override. And `act(List<Animal>)` is a different signature then `act(List<Actor>)`, hence you didn´t override it. Try applying a `@Override` before your `act` Method in the `rabbit` and `fox` class and you will notice a compiler error (since it´s not overriden).

If you would want to override it just change the method to `act(List<Actor>)` in your `rabbit` and `fox` class.

Comment: perfect that works, | got confused because I thought that the Animal class calls the Actor class and the rabbit and fox class call the animal class, Thanks again! @Kevin

Answer (score 4):

The parametrized type of your `List` is the problem here, as it is erased at runtime (see [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), hence defiling virtual method invocation.

You can parametrize your method with `List<? extends Actor>` in the whole class hierarchy to work around this issue.

Something in the lines of:

```
class Actor {

}
class Animal extends Actor {

}
abstract class Abstract {
    abstract void act(List<? extends Actor> actors);
}
class Child extends Abstract {
    @Override
    void act(List<? extends Actor> actors) {
        // TODO something
    }
}
```

Then you invoke it with something in the lines of:

```
new Child().act(new ArrayList<Animal>());
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the compilator requires to find a methode with the same signature as in the abstract class.

An alternative solution is to do something like this :

```
abstract class Actor<T extends Actor> {
    public abstract void act(List<T> actors);
}
abstract class Animal<T extends Animal> extends Actor<T> {
}
class Rabit extends Animal<Rabit> {
    @Override
    public void act(List<Rabit> actors) {
        // TODO 
    }
}
```

This will avoid passing Girafe as argument of the Rabit class :

```
class Girafe extends Animal<Girafe> {
     ...
}


new Rabit().act(new ArrayList<Rabbit>()); // It's OK
new Rabit().act(new ArrayList<Girafe>()); // won't compile
```